# Fluentmigrator firebird trigger

Tags: firebird, fluent-migrator

Is there a way to create a trigger using fluentmigrator / firebirdsql?

When I try this

```
Execute.Sql(@"CREATE TRIGGER TEST_BI FOR 'Test'
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN
    NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_TEST_ID,1)
END
");
```

nothing happens.
I tried the firebird syntax using SET TERM ^; but I get an error then. I also tried calling the DDL statement from a script, with Execute.Script() but still nothing.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Do you commit the transaction in which you create the trigger?

Comment: `SET TERM` is not part of the Firebird syntax, it is a part of tools like ISQL. Also statements in a PSQL block need to end with a semi-colon (only **inside** the PSQL block!).

Comment: I use `FluentMigrator.TransactionBehavior.Default` when defining migration.

Comment: I removed the SET TERM statements from the script file and now I don't get any error, but still no changes in the database. In the same migration I create the table and the sequence also, those two are created correctly and also delete on migrate down. Maybe it has to do with something that @ain said, regarding some transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about Firebird but I'm guessing that you cannot create triggers within a transaction. Check out this wiki page about how to turn off transactions: https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Transaction-modes-for-the-migration-runner

You need to set an attribute on your migration like this:

```
[Migration(201304210958, TransactionBehavior.None)]
```

Comment: I tried both methods, also I separated the trigger inside a new migration, and still nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using the output and outputfile parameters for the runner to see what gets run? https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Command-Line-Runner-Options Is it valid sql that works when running it directly against Firebird?